# How to write json response to CSV file in python ..records seprated by '^'

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv

The following is the json response.

{
"status": "success",
"messages": {
"code": "01010000"
},
"data": {
"msgId": "00240201310140000001",
"tradesInquiry": “6,20180420,,,805151,2^***795393,N,2017070425016382,77575838105600,24924,25,5275,2,1.100000000128036E15,18,1383,1,GIMP01,06637,,2,6001,1183713348,1,0,N,,0,2.8100610400611E14,4098,N,HINDLEVER,,OPTSTK,801532800,14500,PA,,,,,,,,^805151,N,2017070425019234,77575838826496,29135,735,40130,1,1.100000000137094E15,45,29670,1,SK129,06637,,2,6001,1183713360,1,0,N,,0,7.00006732002113E14,4096,N,SCI, ,OPTSTK,796694400,16000,PA,,,,,,,,***”
}
}

I want only bold data to be in the CSV file...Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the JSON in some variable stored which can be used for processing. You can use the csv library to store the row.

Sample code

```
enter code here
import csv
# some JSON: similar to what you have
json_data = {"tradesInquiry":"2,222,312,31231,212,11,2,,33"}

#write the data in csv
with open('test.csv', mode='w') as test_file:
  csv_file_writer = csv.writer(test_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
  csv_file_writer.writerow(json_data["tradesInquiry"]);
```

Comment: the data gets inserted  into csv in wrong format :6,",",2,0,1,8,0,4,2,0,",",",",",",8,0,5,1,5,1,",",2,^,7,9,5,3,9,3,",",N,",",2,0,1,7,0,7,0,4,2,5,0,1,6,3,8,2,",",7,7,5,7,5,8,3,8,1,0,5,6,0,0,",",2,4,9,2,4,",",2,5,",",5,2,7,5,",",2,",",1,.,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,8,0,3,6,E,1,5,",",1,8,",",1,3,8,3,",",1,",",G,I,M,P,0,1,",",0,6,6,3,7,",",",",2,",",6,0,0,1,",",1,1,8,3,7,1,3,3,4,8,",",1,",",0,",",N,",",",",0,",",2,.,8,1,0,0,6,1,0,4,0,0,6,1,1,E,1,4,",",4,0,9,8,",",N,",",H,I,N,D,L,E,V,E,R,",",",",O,P,T,S,T,K,",",8,0,1,5,3,2,8,0,0,",",1,4,5,0,0,",",P,A,",",",",",",",",",",",",",",",",^,8,0,5,1

Comment: What is the expected format ? You have not provided any details in the question.